# Selection Sort Algorithm Python

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sorting

Working on implementing this algorithm using Python. I thought my logic was okay but apparently not as Python is complaining. The while loop is causing issues. If I remove that it works as expected but obviously doesn't sort the whole list. My thought process -> Use Linear Search to find the smallest number -> Append that new number to a list -> Remove that number from the current list -> Loop through that same list (but with smallest number removed) again -> Repeat process until we've gone through the entire list "x" number of times. "x" being equal to the length of the list. The problem I think I'm running into is that the list never gets updated every time I run through the for loop? I keep getting the error `Line 21: ValueError: list.index(x): x not in list`. 
Even though "x" is in the list. Any idea as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
"""
Selection sort algorithm.
"""

import random
ls = []
max_number = 10
while len(ls) < max_number:
    ls.append(random.randint(1,101))
print ls   

def selection_sort(items_to_sort):
    smallest_number = items_to_sort[0]
    current_number = 0
    sorted_items = []
    item_len = len(items_to_sort)
    while item_len > 0:
        for item in items_to_sort[:]:
            if item < smallest_number:
                smallest_number = item
        items_to_sort.pop(items_to_sort.index(smallest_number))    
        sorted_items.append(smallest_number)   
        item_len -= 1    
    return sorted_items
print selection_sort(ls)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like **you're not re-initializing** the `smallest_number` variable, so after the first execution of your `while` loop - you look for a value smaller than the previous value which you just `pop`ed from the list.

When you don't find a value smaller than the previously smallest value which is no longer in the list, you try to `pop` the same `smallest_number` as in the previous iteration of the `while` loop. However, that value is no longer in the `items_to_sort` list which is why you get the `ValueError`

Try moving the line `smallest_number = items_to_sort[0]` to be the first line executed in every iteration of your `while` loop.

Comment: yes u are right, if he doesn't re-initialize the smallst_number, he can never find a smaller number which is smaller than the last smallest number...

Answer (score 1):

After every while loop, you should assign `items_to_sort[0]`  to `smallest_number`

```
current_number = 0
sorted_items = []
item_len = len(items_to_sort)
while item_len > 0:
    smallest_number = items_to_sort[0]
    for item in items_to_sort[:]:
        if item < smallest_number:
            smallest_number = item
    index=items_to_sort.index(smallest_number)
    items_to_sort.pop(index)
    print(items_to_sort)
    sorted_items.append(smallest_number)
    item_len -= 1
return sorted_items
```